# Centralizing column names in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I´m a bit confused as to why there is no widely proposed model of storing your SQLite database structure in Android. Surely it would be nothing but advantageous to keep your column and table names somewhere central for reference, keeping you from going through your entire project when the database changes in structure. How are you handling this? I was thinking of creating a seperate class file called DatabaseConstants with the entire structure in static strings, but I would like to know if there is a better way?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'll do it almost the same, but I keep my constants in the DatabaseHelper class

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) for example to see the column names for Android Contacts.

Comment: Would it be unecessary to start creating a content provider if I have no plans on sharing my application-data with other applications?

Comment: I was asking myself too. At the end I just use a custom DatabaseAdapter. If I need to share data, I only need to build content provider on top of it.